# Nhibernate and like statement on XML field

Tags: nhibernate

I have a wrapped fluent nhibernate framework that I'm reusing and have no control over the actual mapping.

In my entity object I have a property mapped as string to an XML column in sql.

Hence when I run a query like:

```
var myResult = (from myTable in DataManager.Session.Query<Table>()
                      where myTable.thatXmlFieldWhichIsMappedAsString.Contains(AnXmlSnippet))
                      select myTable).FirstOrDefault();
```

It is trying to use the LIKE operator in SQL which is invalid on that column type.

How can I get around this without having to select all the rows and converting to List first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case, that we do not need .Query() *(LINQ)*, and we can use `Criteria` query or `QueryOver`, we can use conversion:

```
// the projection of the column with xml
// casted to nvarchar
var projection = Projections
      .Cast(NHibernateUtil.StringClob
          , Projections.Property("thatXmlFieldWhichIsMappedAsString"));

// criteria filtering with LIKE
var criteria = Restrictions.Like(projection, "searched xml");

// query and result
var query = session.QueryOver<MyEntity>()
    .Where(criteria)
    ;
var result = query 
    .SingleOrDefault<MyEntity>()
    ;
```

From my experience this could lead to conversion into small nvarchar(255) - sql server... Then we can do it like this:

```
var projection = Projections
   .SqlProjection("CAST(thatXmlFieldWhichIsMappedAsString as nvarchar(max)) AS str"
       , new string[]{}
       , new NHibernate.Type.IType[]{}
   );
```